# Referencing Ansible group variables to inventory

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have an inventory file `inv.yml` with a list of hosts which looks like this:

```yaml
---
all:
  hosts:
    csr1:
      ansible_host: 192.168.10.11
      os: ios
    csr2:
      # etc...
```

I have a `group_vars` folder containing a few files. One of them is `all.yml` and I can see that all hosts are getting variables from this file. I also have two other files `amers.yml` and `emear.yml`. Each contains a specific snmp config per region which looks like that:

```yaml
---
snmp:
  contact: Joe Smith
  location: Americas
  communities:
    - community: public
      type: ro
```

My problem is that I don't know how to reference which host should use the `emear` or `amers` group variable file.

How can I correctly reference `amers` and `emear` variable files for specific devices in inventory?

Comment: What is the logic here? How one would be `emear` and another `amers` is it on a fact of the host, on a variable in the inventory, in the group, else?

Comment: So the logic here is let say host: csr1 is in emear so it should use variables and values from emear.yml file meanwhile csr2 is in amers so it should use variables and values from amers.yml. The problem here is I'm not really sure how should I reference that in inv.yml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inventory should look like (example, put the correct hosts in each group)

```yaml
---
all:
  children:
    amers:
      hosts:
        csr1:
          ansible_host: 1.2.3.4 
    emear:
      hosts:
        csr2:
          ansible_host: 5.6.7.8
```

Now each group will receive the variables defined in the respective `group_vars/amers.yml` and `group_vars/emear.yml` files.

This is a very short intro, there is a lot more to know about how to construct your inventory, where to put your variables exactly (to skip possible variables precedence nightmares...), good practice, etc. You can find all this in the ansible documentation: [How to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure your groups are defined. Try creating a `hosts.ini` (see below) and passing it to `ansible-playbook`

```sh
$ ansible-inventory -i hosts.ini --list
```

Files:

```
├── group_vars
│   ├── all.yml
│   ├── amers.yml
│   └── emers.yml
└── hosts.ini
```

hosts.ini

```
[amers]
192.168.10.11

[emers]
192.168.10.12
```

group_vars/amers.yml

```yaml
---
snmp:
  contact: Joe Smith
  location: Americas
  communities:
    - community: public
      type: ro
```

group_vars/emers.yml

```yaml
---
snmp:
  contact: Nobody
```

group_vars/all.yml

```yaml
---
os: ios
```

Comment: That works indeed but I'm just curious: why moving the inventory to `.ini` when OP provided an example with a `.yml` one which is valid and simply lacking the groups (as you perfectly pointed out)?

Comment: Building an inventory file using yaml is lengthier. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html for details

Comment: Thanks for sending me back to the documentation I already linked in my answer;) If you consider a few extra-line per file lengthier, all right. I don't, I find the yaml format easier to read and much more flexible when it comes to adding vars for example, easier to use with tools out of ansible if needed. And last, that was the format OP used in first place, that had no mistake whatsoever in his question, and I would not change it in my answer without at least explaining why. Just my 2 cent (and your up-vote is still there ;)).

Comment: i like that you can do `[group_name:vars]` or `[group_name:children]` with the ini format - but maybe its because i learned the ini syntax first is why i prefer it

Comment: => https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/7ed1131a32f3af5c8bb9848375648319